# Add a toggle functionality to a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My basic requirement is to add a dropdown in my site. I need when someone clicks on a text, a form will show there with a animate effect from top to bottom and will again hide if we click on the text again.

You can visit my page where I want this feature:

http://test.techkalph.com/listing-plain-heading/?filter=all&type=travel-travel-agents&submit=

Here on the right sidebar, on the very top, you can see a button saying Search by Location. When you inspect that button, you can see there is a form under a div below that button which I have made display:none to hide that.

I want to show that form when click on the button and again hide that upon clicking there (Toggle feature) with some animate effect will be fine.

I have added this script  there for that purpose which you can also find in the inspect element:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
            $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").show();
        });
        $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
            $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working. Am I doing something wrong? Please visit my above page and help me to show the form on click and hide again on click.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js looks to be redundant: In the same click handler, you're showing **and** hiding the div - effectively, you're doing nothing :)

Instead, use a single call to `$(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").toggle()`

Something along the lines of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
        $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").toggle();
    });
});
```

I tested this in the console and it works fine.

If you **must** use separate handlers for whatever reason (I know: sometimes projects have very odd requirements), you should use a flag-test operation:

1. set a boolean, something like `var advIsShown=false`
2. when showing\hiding, toggle the boolean state.
3. test for this state before you decide whether to call `.show()` or `.hide()`

Comment: Hello Kevin,

Thanks. Now I have this code:

  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
     $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").show();
    });
    $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
     $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").hide();
    });
   });
  </script>
Can you please share the complete code I have to use? The code you have mentioned has only addressed to the form. But the button is not linked anywhere so that upon clicking on that it will work.

Comment: Managed to adjust that also.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this script instead to make the form toggle with a time interval:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".section-sidebar #custom_location").click(function(){
            $(".section-sidebar div #directory-advance-search-form").toggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Users can adjust the 1000 as per their requirement here.

Thank you again Kevin.